# sorting scandir by date Descending order

Tags: php

i am using this code for listing a directory

```
foreach(scandir('back/1') as $folder){
    if (in_array($folder, array('.', '..'))) continue;
    echo basename($folder); // get folder's name
}
```

but i want to sort the directories input by modifecation time.

how to do it.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$files = glob('back/1/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ($files as $f){
  $tmp[basename($f)] = filemtime($f);
}
asort($tmp);
$files = array_keys($tmp);
```

Comment: i want it by Descending order

Comment: @Pin http://php.net/array <-- you're welcome to choose any appropriate function suits any your wishes, whims and caprices.

Answer (score 0):

I am adapting Your Common Sense's answer to sort by descending last modified time stamp. The sort function is from joseph dot morphy's comment on the [PHP glob spec page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

```
if (!function_exists('sort_by_mtime'))   {
    function sort_by_mtime($file1,$file2) {
        $time1 = filemtime($file1);
        $time2 = filemtime($file2);
        if ($time1 == $time2) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($time1 < $time2) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}

$files = glob('back/1/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ($files as $f){
  $tmp[basename($f)] = filemtime($f);
}
usort($tmp,"sort_by_mtime");
$files = array_keys($tmp);
```