# search server for newly added files with PHP

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to write a cronjob in php to search a server for newly uploaded files. Every night the server adds a csv file, which must be pulled to my local server, and inserted into my database. I can read the csv file, insert it into the database, and everything else on my end, except figure out how to scan the directory for the new file every night. Does anybody have any general suggestions for going about this?

Comment: Generally, PHP programs are temporary. They perform a task and die - they don't wait for something to happen. Therefore, the best way around making cronjobs is either making a cronjob on your *nix environment and calling your PHP script or use a free cronjob service - there a plenty, just Google it.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen: Just saying, cron was already part of the tags ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display latest uploaded image first? (PHP+CSS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557980/how-can-i-display-latest-uploaded-image-first-phpcss)

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

1. Scan the directory, order files by date, and record the date of the most recent file
2. On subsequent scans, compare the date of the newest file with the recorded date
3. If the date is newer, a new file has been uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

While you can technically do it with bare PHP, I'd go for the `find` command:

```
$files = explode("\0",`find /path/to/dir -mtime -1 -iname '*.csv' -print0`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `scandir`, make an array `$allFiles` that contains all the files. Create another array `$oldFiles` containing all the existing files in the directory. After that, performing `array_diff($allFiles, oldFiles)` will yield an array containing only the new files.